# Turning off hammer.js touch events using onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, hammer.js

I've just finished constructing my carousel slider with touch events for a website I'm building. Currently trying to figure out how I can disable the touch events`(hammer)` using on click events. Here is the code that I've been working on

The class `.slider-layout` enables the carousel while the class `.tile-layout` disable the carousel and transforms the layout in a card view layout

---

**Update #1**

I tried removing the class that binds the hammer.js but didn't work.

```js
var activeSlide = 0;
    $('.faculty-carousel').attr('data-slide', '0');
    
    
    
    $('.tile-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('tile-view');
        })
    })
    
    
    $('.prev').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    
        var carouselWrapper     = $(this).closest('.faculty-carousel'),
            facultyProfilePanel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            facultyProfileCount = facultyProfilePanel.length,
            viewPortSize        = $(window).width(),
            carousel            = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items'),
            position            = 0,
            currentSlide        = parseInt(carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
        // Check if data-slide attribute is greater than 0
        if (currentSlide > 0) {
            // Decremement current slide
            currentSlide--;
            // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
            var transformPercentage = -1 * currentSlide / facultyProfileCount * 100;
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transformPercentage + '% )');
    
            // Update data-slide attribute
            carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
            activeSlide = currentSlide;
        }
    });
    
    $('.next').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // store variable relevent to clicked slider
    
        var carouselWrapper     = $(this).closest('.faculty-carousel'),
            facultyProfilePanel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            facultyProfileCount = facultyProfilePanel.length,
            viewPortSize   = $(window).width(),
            carousel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items'),
            position = 0,
            currentSlide = parseInt(carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
        // Check if dataslide is less than the total slides
        if (currentSlide < facultyProfileCount - 1) {
            // Increment current slide
            currentSlide++;
            // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
            var transformPercentage = -1 * currentSlide / facultyProfileCount * 100;
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transformPercentage + '% )');
    
            // Update data-slide attribute
            carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
            activeSlide = currentSlide;
        }
    })
    
    
    function touchCarousel() {
        $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items').each(function() {
    
            // create a simple instance
            // by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
    
            var direction,
                touchSlider = this,
                mc = new Hammer.Manager(this),
                itemLength = $(this).find('li').length,
                count = 0,
                slide = $(this),
                timer;
    
            var sliderWrapper = slide,
                slideItems = sliderWrapper.find('li'),
                //slider = sliderWrapper.find('li'),
                totalPanels = slideItems.length,
                currentSlide = parseInt(sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
            // mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
            //   direction = ev.type;
            // });
    
            mc.add(new Hammer.Pan({
                threshold: 0,
                pointers: 0
            }));
            
            mc.on('pan', function(e) {
                var percentage = 100 / totalPanels * e.deltaX / window.innerWidth;
                var transformPercentage = percentage - 100 / totalPanels * activeSlide;
                touchSlider.style.transform = 'translateX( ' + transformPercentage + '% )';
                var sliderWrapper = $(e.target).closest('.faculty-carousel')
    
    
                if (e.isFinal) { // NEW: this only runs on event end
    
                    var newSlide = activeSlide;
                    if (percentage < 0)
                        newSlide = activeSlide + 1;
                    else if (percentage > 0)
                        newSlide = activeSlide - 1;
                    goToSlide(newSlide, sliderWrapper);
                }
            });
    
    
            var goToSlide = function(number, sliderWrapper) {
                if (number < 0)
                    activeSlide = 0;
                else if (number > totalPanels - 1)
                    activeSlide = totalPanels - 1
                else
                    activeSlide = number;
    
                sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', activeSlide);
    
                touchSlider.classList.add('slide-animation');
                var percentage = -(100 / totalPanels) * activeSlide;
                touchSlider.style.transform = 'translateX( ' + percentage + '% )';
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    touchSlider.classList.remove('slide-animation');
                }, 400);
    
            };
        });
    }
    
    
    function panelSizing() {
    
        // var activeSlide = 0;
        // $('.faculty-carousel').attr('data-slide', '0');
    
    
        var viewPortSize        = $(window).width(),
            carouselWrapper = $('.faculty-carousel')
        ;
        
        //Set Panel Size based on viewport
    
        if (viewPortSize <= 1920 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 5
        }
    
    
        if (viewPortSize < 1024 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 4
        }
    
        if (viewPortSize < 768 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 3
        } 
    
        if (viewPortSize < 480 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize
        }
        
        carouselWrapper.each(function(){
            var wrapper = $(this);
            // wrapper.attr('data-slide', '0');
    
            var facultyPanel = wrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            profileCount = facultyPanel.length,
            // activeSlide         = 0,
            carousel            = wrapper.find('.faculty-items');
    
            carousel.outerWidth( profilePanelSize * profileCount );
            facultyPanel.outerWidth(profilePanelSize);
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + 0 + '% )');
        });
    }
    
    $('.tile-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('tile-view');
            $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items').css('transform', 'translateX(' + 0 + '% )');
        })
    });
    
    $('.slider-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('tile-view');
        })
    })
    
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        panelSizing();
        touchCarousel()
    
    })
    
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        panelSizing();
        touchCarousel()
    
    })
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 100%;
      font: inherit;
      vertical-align: baseline; }
    
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
      display: block; }
    
    body {
      line-height: 1; }
    
    ol, ul {
      list-style: none; }
    
    blockquote, q {
      quotes: none; }
    
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
      content: '';
      content: none; }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0; }
    
    .faculty-items.tile-view {
      display: flex !important;
      flex-wrap: wrap !important;
      width: 100% !important; }
    
    .faculty-items li {
      height: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative; }
      .faculty-items li > a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        user-drag: none;
        user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none; }
    
    .faculty-items li:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: grey; }
    
    .faculty-items li:nth-child(even), .faculty-items a:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: aqua; }
    
    .faculty-items {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      right: 0;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear; }
    
    .faculty-carousel .controls {
      display: block; }
    
    /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
    
    <div class="slider-layout">
        slider layout
    </div>
    
    <div class="tile-layout">
        tile layout
    </div>
    
    <div class="faculty-carousel">
        <ul class="faculty-items">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
        </ul>
    
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="prev">
            prev
            </div>
    
            <div class="next">
            next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="faculty-carousel">
        <ul class="faculty-items">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="prev">
            prev
            </div>
    
            <div class="next">
            next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faculty-carousel">
        <ul class="faculty-items">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
        </ul>
    
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="prev">
            prev
            </div>
    
            <div class="next">
            next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to disable touch events make a use of `off` function.

I've added another link for this action:

```
$(".toggle-touch-events").click(function() {
    mc.touchEvents = !mc.touchEvents;
    if (mc.touchEvents) {
        mc.on('pan', onPanEvent);
    } else {
        mc.off('pan');
    }
});
```

Please check the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e6unh583/2/